# What am I missing? NumberFormatException error

Tags: java, string, file, casting

I want to read from a txt file which contains just numbers. Such file is in UTF-8, and the numbers are separated only by new lines (no spaces or any other things) just that. Whenever i call Integer.valueOf(myString), i get the exception.

This exception is really strange, because if i create a predefined string, such as "56\n", and use .trim(), it works perfectly. But in my code, not only that is not the case, but the exception texts says that what it couldn't convert was "54856". I have tried to introduce a new line there, and then the error text says it couldn't convert "54856
"
With that out of the question, what am I missing?

```java
File ficheroEntrada = new File("C:\\in.txt");
FileReader entrada =new FileReader(ficheroEntrada);
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(entrada);

String s = input.readLine();
System.out.println(s);
Integer in;
in = Integer.valueOf(s.trim());
System.out.println(in);
```

The exception text reads as follows:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "54856"
    at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:68)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:658)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:989)
    at Quicksort.main(Quicksort.java:170)
```

The file in.txt consists of:

```
54856
896
54
53
2
5634
```

Comment: If this is under Windows a carriage return may be in your string as well (`'\r'`).

Comment: Hidden characters, perhaps? Try to print out the array of characters from the string, using `Arrays.toString`.

Comment: What type of object is `input`? Can you show us the line where you create it?

Comment: Can you please check on the ordinal number of the characters in the string? Might those be unicode characters outside of the ascii-range? 0-9 should usually be inside ascii, but maybe those are not the default 0-9 chars.

Comment: I could be helpful to include the printed output, something like `System.out.println(".." + s + "..");`, It's strange that trim doesn't remove the `\r`

Comment: Take a look at update @AlbertoSantosAraus

Answer (score 2):

Well, aparently it had to do with Windows and those \r that it uses... I just tried executing it on a Linux VM and it worked. Thanks to everyone that answered!!

Comment: Take a look at my updated code Alberto and try it in Windows too. @AlbertoSantosAraus

Answer (score 1):

Try reading the file with `Scanner` class has use it's `hasNextInt()` method to identify what you are reading is `Integer` or not. This will help you find out what String/character is causing the issue

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    File ficheroEntrada = new File(
            "C:\\in.txt");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(ficheroEntrada);
    while (scan.hasNext()) {
        if (scan.hasNextInt()) {
            System.out.println("found integer" + scan.nextInt());
        } else {
            System.out.println("not integer" + scan.next());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you have a `leading/trailing whitespaces` in your input, something like:

```
String s = " 5436";
System.out.println(s);
Integer in;
in = Integer.valueOf(s.trim());
System.out.println(in);
```

Use `trim()` on string to get rid of it.

```
UPDATE 2:
```

If your file contains something like:

```
54856\n
896
54\n
53
2\n
5634
```

then use following code for it:

```
  ....your code
    FileReader enter = new FileReader(file);
    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(enter);
    String currentLine;
    while ((currentLine = input.readLine()) != null) {
    Integer in;
    //get rid of non-numbers
    in = Integer.valueOf(currentLine.replaceAll("\\D+",""));
    System.out.println(in);
    ...your code
```

Comment: Yes, I specified that with the use of trim, the error remains. That's what's confusing me.

Comment: Can you show us content of your in file? @AlbertoSantosAraus

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ensure parsability of a string, you could use a Pattern and Regex that.

```
Pattern intPattern = Pattern.compile("\\-?\\d+");
Matcher matcher = intPattern.matcher(input);
if (matcher.find()) {
    int value = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(0));
    // ... do something with the result.
} else {
    // ... handle unparsable line.
}
```

This pattern allows any numbers and optionally a minus before (without whitespace). It should definetly parse, unless it is too long. I don't know how it handles that, but your example seems to contain mostly short integers, so this should not matter.